# How can show the element I've been choices in select box Multi?

Tags: laravel, jquery-select2

I have this select box Multi choices from [select2](https://select2.org/)
and in the edit page I wanna to bring the choices I'd already choose

code of blade :

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name of Attendees *</label>

    <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="attendees[]" multiple="multiple" style="width:100%">

        <option></option>

        @foreach ($users as $user)
            <option value="{{ $user->id }}" {{ $edit->attendees == $user->id ? "selected":"" }} >{{ $user->name }}</option>
        @endforeach

    </select>
</div>
```

Here I try to bring the choices by this code but not working

```
<option value="{{ $user->id }}" {{ $edit->attendees == $user->id ? "selected":"" }} >{{ $user->name }}</option>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make this

`{{ $edit->attendees == $user->id ? "selected":"" }}`

like this:

```
{{ in_array($user->id,$edit->attendees->pluck('user_id')) ? "selected":"" }}
```

or cast `attendees` as array like this:

```
 protected $casts=['attendees'=>'array'];
```